# Am I cheating on this AI challenge?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

So on HackerRank under the AI section, my solution to the "Bot saves princess - 2" problem reads the input for the princess's position. Is the solution supposed to do that? I don't really see how else it can be solved efficiently.

## Problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/saveprincess2

## Solution

```
def nextMove(r,c, pr, pc):
    if r < pr:
        r += 1
        return("DOWN")
    elif r > pr:
        r -= 1
        return("UP")
    
    if c < pc:
        c += 1
        return("RIGHT")
    elif c > pc:
        c -= 1
        return("LEFT")
        
n = int(input())
r,c = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()]
grid = []
pr = 0
pc = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    inp = input()
    if inp.find('p') >= 0:
        pr = i
        pc = inp.find('p')
    grid.append(inp)

print(nextMove(r,c,pr, pc))
```

Comment: the position of the princess is an input so I don't see why not. They want you to get the shortest path to the princess in a grid without any obstacles from what I understood

Comment: It's not really a question about programming but more about understanding instructions - the only one capable of answering is the one who posted the question. Luckily, he has done so - check the discussion tab there.

Comment: Aside from that fact that old school AI used to "cheat" in ways like this, in a contest of wits, its not cheating to be intelligent. Its the only winning move.

Comment: If I remember correctly (a year or two ago I looked at this), there's harder versions of the princess-themed challenges later on, that give less input. I think this is just the 'tutorial' challenge for making your function behave correctly (e.g. outputting a single command each time it's called)

Comment: Okay I thought so. It seemed a bit too easy...

Comment: @Taekahn, You're right. They want you to parse the grid for that information. 

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/saveprincess2/forum/comments/15921

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting a problem definition rather than the code itself - unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I am mistaken, but can you not find the princesses position by finding the index of the 'p' in the grid, as it does not seem to be specified as an input:

```
def find_princess(grid):
    N = len(grid)
    for i in range(grid):
       for j in range(grid):
            if grid[i][j] == 'P'
            return i,j
```

Comment: Yes you can. The input is as follows:

[5]
[2 3]
[-----]
[-----]
[p--m-]
[-----]
[-----]

Where each set of braces is one input. My code works and gets full marks.

Comment: well by parsing the grid as above solves the 'my solution to the "Bot saves princess - 2" problem reads the input for the princess's position' part of your question then